# How to select rows up to a certain value only in POSTGRES using window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the following table named test and would like to only select it up to the row above the **1st** delete statement of the same id ('1144QQT'). So, from 2021-03-01 to 2021-06-02 (only the bold ones). So, this excludes the row with the delete statement. It does include many more ids of different types and more of the same type.

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id                BIGINT       PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
barcode_id        VARCHAR      NOT NULL,
date              DATE         NOT NULL,
keyword           VARCHAR      NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test
VALUES
(1, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert'),
(2, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert'),
(3, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert'),
(4, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert'),
(5, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert'),
(6, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert'),
(7, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert'),
(8, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert'),
(9, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert'),
(10, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert'),
(11, '1144QQT', '2021-03-01'::date, 'insert');
```

| id | barcode_id | date | keyword |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **1144QQT** | **2021-03-01** | **insert** |
| **2** | **1144QQT** | **2021-03-02** | **adjust** |
| 3 | 5588aTT | 2021-03-03 | delete |
| 4 | 4477aTT | 2021-03-04 | adjust |
| 5 | 5588aTT | 2021-03-05 | adjust |
| **6** | **1144QQT** | **2021-03-06** | **adjust** |
| 7 | 1144QQT | 2021-03-07 | delete |
| 8 | 1144QQT | 2021-03-08 | insert |
| 9 | 1144QQT | 2021-03-09 | adjust |
| 10 | 1144QQT | 2021-03-10 | delete |
| 11 | 4477aTT | 2021-03-11 | delete |

So, the output I am expecting is this:

| id | barcode_id | date | keyword |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1144QQT | 2021-03-01 | insert |
| 2 | 1144QQT | 2021-03-02 | adjust |
| 6 | 1144QQT | 2021-03-06 | adjust |

How can I do this with postgres? Is it possible to do this with window functions?

Comment: You seem to already know that window functions exist and that they can be used here because you tagged them (well, you tried but added a space instead of a hyphen between the words, I corrected that for you). So you should go ahead and try something yourself. If that doesn't solve it, then [edit] the question and include your **reasonable** attempt together with a **detailed** explanation what went with it (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: @Kraigolas hahaha yes, I think I know what a where statement is. I edited the question to make it clearer, or so I hope.

Comment: @sticky bit I mean I tried. This statement is basically a subquery to a bigger query. So, I just wanted to simplify it. Cant figure it out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, this logic would seem to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = '1144QQT' and t.keyword <> 'delete';
```

This makes the assumption that there are no rows for an id after the delete -- but that seems reasonable and is consistent with your sample data.

For your specific question, one method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = '1144QQT' and
      t.id < (select min(t2.date)
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.keyword <> 'delete'
             );
```

The above version version requires that there be a "delete" -- it is unclear based on your question if that is a requirement.  An alternative uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(date) filter (where keyword = 'delete') over (partition by id) as min_delete_date
      where t.id = '1144QQT' 
     ) t
where date < min_delete_date;
```

If you want all rows if there is no "delete", then add `or min_delete_date is null` to the outer `where`.

Comment: Hi there, but it does include many more ids of different types and more of the same type. I just want to Select it up to row above the 1st delete statement of the same id. So, from 2021-03-01 to 2021-03-06 excluding the row with the delete keywoard.

Comment: Something like that last solution is actually what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUM()` window function to identify the rows before the first row with `keyword = 'delete'`:

```
SELECT id, date, keyword
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM((keyword = 'delete')::int) OVER (ORDER BY date) grp
  FROM tablename
  WHERE id = '1144QQT'
) t
WHERE grp = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0a8737c0e4dbcbe3c2b032219df91fa4).
Results:

| id | date | keyword |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1144QQT | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | insert |
| 1144QQT | 2021-03-02 00:00:00 | adjust |
| 1144QQT | 2021-03-06 00:00:00 | adjust |

Comment: This is also a nice solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to Select it up to row above the 1st delete statement of the same id.

`NOT EXISTS()` to the rescue: (NOTE `date` is a **reserved word**, and a bad name for a column)

```
SELECT *
FROM ztable zt
WHERE zt.zid = '1144QQT'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM ztable nx
    WHERE nx.zid = zt.zid
    AND nx.zkeyword = 'delete'
    AND nx.zdate <= zt.zdate
    );
```